# Setup for getter and setter in a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, plugins, getter-setter

I need a example of a very simple/basic way to do getter and setter for some variables and options on a custom jQuery plugin. I've found a example of in the [jQuery UI docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/):

```
// getter
var disabled = $( ".selector" ).button( "option", "disabled" );

// setter
$( ".selector" ).button( "option", "disabled", true );
```

looks weird, but I think its because jQuery conventions are that you are only allowed to bind only one method per plugin on the jQuery. So the question is, does anyone have a simple plugin that does this, because I couldn't figure out how they did it in the button-plugin.

Comment: you can try out with `http://starter.pixelgraphics.us/` to start your plugin development. It is good way for starter

Comment: I don't think it's a good way because it creates multiple keys on the jQuery object for on single plugin `$.fn.myPlugin` and `$.fn.getMyPlugin` also not sure if there should be a `$.MyPlugin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this [blog-post](http://www.virgentech.com/blog/2009/10/building-object-oriented-jquery-plugin.html) about the same issues, I really like how he did this. Saving the object into `$elem.data()` makes it easy to open the object to the outside world.